# Optimize query: Filter Values Contained in Multiple Ranges

Tags: postgresql

### Background

In the fiddle below, I have two tables. The first table contains a column with a numeric value (e.g. `int`). The second table contains rows of numeric ranges (stored in two columns that hold the “low” and “high” limits of the range).

### The Problem

The query in the fiddle works, using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to produce the expected results. I can add indices to speed queries, but would appreciate thoughts on how to generate `SQL` to achieve a more optimal query plan than that provided in the fiddle.

### Example

DB Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5d7c8d017be8bb72fa406c45500b3611)

### Other Notes

Solutions need not be portable (so long as they work in `PostgreSQL`), but no third-party solutions, please.

### System

PostgreSQL v11.2

Fedora 29

Comment: Where's the JOIN you mentioned in the fiddle?

Comment: @Vérace Perhaps I’m abusing the term — thought that was implicitly performed by the query planner when not joining on specific column(s). If it makes a difference, could add an identifier column on which to specify a `JOIN` (in the trivial case, would just use a static value like `1` for each row in the tables)